# Problema al instalar Mayavi 4.5 en Python 3

Tags: python, numpy, conda, anaconda

No logro instalar correctamente Mayavi 4.5 sobre Python 3. Tengo una instalación completa de Anaconda (la versión de 64 bits) sobre Python 3.5 e instalé Mayavi mediante:

```
conda install -c menpo mayavi=4.5.0.
```

En el momento en que intento cargar la librería, obtengo el siguiente error:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/flop/Desktop/untitled19/b.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mayavi import mlab
  File "C:\Users\flop\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mayavi-4.5.0-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\mayavi\mlab.py", line 27, in <module>
    from mayavi.tools.camera import view, roll, yaw, pitch, move
  File "C:\Users\flop\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mayavi-4.5.0-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\mayavi\tools\camera.py", line 19, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 no es una aplicación Win32 válida.
________________________________________________________________________________
Please check your numpy installation. If you need numpy,
'easy_install numpy' will install it.
http://numpy.scipy.org


Process finished with exit code 1
```

He probado con la versión de 32 bits pero no sé cómo instalar en ella Mayavi 4.5. También he actualizado la versión de numpy a la 1.10 ya que sobre el papel mi instalación de Mayavi 4.5 funciona sobre ella, pero no he logrado nada. Agradecería que alguien me comentase por lo menos qué cosas intentar para solucionarlo.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3):

[mayavi](/questions/tagged/mayavi) requiere tener instalado [vtk](/questions/tagged/vtk). Si no está en el canal oficial de anaconda seguramente tengas que instalar las dependencias a mano. Prueba lo siguiente, si algo ya lo tienes instalado no hace falta que lo vuelvas a instalar (si quieres que esté dentro de un *virtualenv* o dentro de un *conda-env* actívalo antes):

```
conda install numpy # seguramente ya lo tengas instalado
conda install setuptools # seguramente ya lo tengas intalado
conda install -c conda-forge traits=4.5.0 
conda install -c clinicalgraphics vtk=7.0.0 
conda install -c menpo mayavi=4.5.0
```

Otra opción, que no he probado, sería usando [pip](/questions/tagged/pip) y la [maravillosa página de Christoph Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). En esa página tienes *wheels* de los paquetes anteriores. Puedes descargarlos y, desde la carpeta donde se han descargado, hacer (ten en cuenta lo mismo que antes para que se instale dentro del *virtual/conda-env*):

```
pip install nombre_del_paquete
```

Por ejemplo,

```
pip install mayavi-4.5.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

Yo acabo de usar [conda](/questions/tagged/conda) para hacer la instalación en un **win32**, cambiando alguna cosilla de las instrucciones que te he puesto ya que tú lo quieres para **win64**, y se ha instalado sin problemas.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias Kiko! Lo probaré en cuanto pueda y comentaré que tal me ha ido. Seguro que de una u otra forma, con tu ayuda, lo logro.

Comment: ¡Lo he conseguido al fin! Como suele pasar a veces, al final desinstalé todo y volví a instalar Anaconda3 de 32 bits. Y no hubo el mas mínimo problema. Cuando tenga ganas probaré la versión de 64 bits de Anaconda3 a ver si también funciona correctamente sobre Windows 8.1 (y dejaré constancia aquí por si puede servir a alguien). ¡Gracias de nuevo!.

Comment: Estoy intentando instalar a la vez la versión de Anaconda3 de 64 bits con Mayavi y no puedo. ¿Se pueden tener las dos versiones instaladas y funcionar independientemete? En caso afirmativo, ¿cómo haría para instalar Mayavi 4.5 en la versión de 64 bits?

Comment: No creo que puedas tener dos anacondas instalados sin conflictos de rutas y demás. ¿Para qué querrías tener dos anacondas?

Comment: Era casi una curiosidad. Lo malo es que he intentado instalar desde cero (quitada la de 32 bits) la de 64 bits y Mayavi 4.5 no va. El comportamiento es casi como si tuviese un SO de 32 bits, cuando el que tengo es un Windows 8.1 de 64. No se incluso si generar otra pregunta sobre ello.

Comment: También está la duda de si Mayavi 4.5 funciona correctamente sobre 64 bits. Sobre el papel si, pero nunca se sabe.

Comment: Esta tarde podría probar en un win64 pero no debería dar problemas. Dime qué es lo que falla de los pasos que te marco en la respuesta.

Comment: En la versión de 32 bits todo funcionó correctamente con conda tras instalarlo todo "desde cero". En la de 64 bits tuve problemas con la última instrucción conda que indicas (la que instala Mayavi) y tuve que usar la forma alternativa que me comentaste (pip tras descargar el wheel indicado) para conseguir que todo funcionase bien.

Comment: La solucion de kikocorreoso no functiona con pyqt5: pyqt4 tiene que ser installado: conda install pyqt=4